# Is the limit of càdlàg functions càdlàg?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Is the pointwise limit of càdlàg functions càdlàg? If not which are the weaker conditions to assure it? I cannot find a counterexample

Comment: [Càdlàg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A0dl%C3%A0g): "right continuous with left limits". Had not heard that one before.

Comment: glad that you got something new ;)

Comment: I used to drive a Cadlag.

Comment: That's haute mathématique ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple counter-example of a cumulative distribution function corresponding to when $\Pr(X_n =\frac1n ) = 1$:
$$F_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0   & \qquad x \lt \frac1n \\ 1 &  \qquad \frac1n \le x\end{cases}$$

so the pointwise limit is 
$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0   &  \qquad x \le 0 \\ 1 &  \qquad 0 \lt x\end{cases}$$ 
which is not càdlàg but càglàd (or làdcàg?) and so not the cumulative distribution function of a random variable almost surely $0$.

Answer (score 5):

What about $$
f_n\colon x\in[0,2] \mapsto \begin{cases}
x^n & x \leq 1 \\
(2-x)^n & x > 1
\end{cases}$$
?
The pointwise limit is the function 
$$
f\colon x\in[0,2] \mapsto \begin{cases}
1 & x = 1 \\
0 & x \neq 1
\end{cases}$$
which is not càdlàg.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0\\ 1 & 0\le x<\frac{1}{n}\\ 0 & \frac{1}{n}\le x\end{cases}$$
The limit is $0$ everywhere, except $1$ at $0$.